# How do I retrieve a certificate's Private Key from Az Key Vault for use in the correct state?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to retrieve the Private Key from a certificate generated and stored in Azure Key Vault using the first few lines noted in the Powershell example in this [documentation article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/how-to-export-certificate?tabs=azure-powershell). I've ensured that exporting the Private Key is enabled for the Certificate record.

I'm using `Connect-AzAccount -Identity` to auth to Azure within the function. However, when I call `Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate` with a valid `-VaultName` and `-Vault` I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: Key not valid for use in specified state.
Exception             :Type       :
Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicExceptionTargetSite :Name          : ProtectOrUnprotectDeclaringType : 
System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedDataMemberType    : MethodModule        : System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.dllStackTrace :at 
..........
```

I've got RBAC permissions set up on the KeyVault with the `Key Vaults Secret User` role assigned to the Function App.

What do I need to do to get the Key Vault secret in the correct 'specified state' to use?

*Note that if I ignore this error it seems I can successfully use the private key to auth when passed to `Connect-MgGraph`. For this reason I'm not convinced this error is actually an indication of a functional issue, but it still means the Az Func fails. The following code is an extract from the function to indicate its use. However I do get the error with both the `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret` and `Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate` cmdlets and so it seems to be a lower level issue:*

```
$certValue = (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "<VAULTNAME>" -Name "<CERTNAME>").SecretValue | ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText
$pfxCert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 -ArgumentList @([Convert]::FromBase64String($certValue),"",[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)
...
Connect-MgGraph -ClientId $client_id -TenantId $tenantId -Certificate $pfxCert
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first code snippet, you're grabbing the certificate *as a certificate*.  Key vault does not return the certificate's private key when using this method.

In the second code snippet (that works), you're grabbing the entire certificate in its base-64 encoded state *as a secret*, which includes the private key.  The code then converts it into an X509 certificate for use.

You should follow the second method.  I blogged about this:
https://azidentity.azurewebsites.net/post/2018/07/03/azure-key-vault-certificates-are-secrets

Comment: I actually came across your website before posting my question. While I agree that your method (and my 2nd method) "works", it still produces the 'specified state' exception when running the Az Function.

Comment: I feel like you have mixed up questions:  Which problem are you having?
1) Downloading the cert using the GetAzKeyVaultCertificate cmdlet?
2) Downloading the cert with its private key?

Comment: Practically, I'm not having either problem - I can use the above Powershell commands to successfully retrieve and use the certificate and its private key. However, I do receive the error noted in my post (when running `Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate`). This seems to be misleading due to the aforementioned success - but the purpose of this SO question is to ascertain why I'm receiving the error and what I can do to suppress it.